# Lower-bound probability of non-centered quadratic form

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, inequalities, measure-concentration

Let $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2I)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-centered ($\mu\neq 0$) Gaussian vector with independent coordinates. I'm wondering if there is any sharp lower bound of the following probability:
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X^TAX - \mathbb{E}(X^TAX) \geq \delta\right)$$
where $A$ is a symmetric matrix and $\delta>0$.

I know that when $X$ is centered, the upper bound is well-known, which is the Hanson-Wright inequality. However, in my case, $X$ is not centered and I'm interested in the lower bound.

Comment: It seems like you are interested in anti-concentration inequalities, or small ball probabilities. This paper might be useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00829.

Comment: Do you mean you want the infimum over all symmetric matrices $A$? If so, that way of using the word "where" is not the clearest use of language.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah you are looking for the anti concentration inequality for Gaussian polynomials. For degree $d$ polynomials the probability that you lie in an $\epsilon$ interval is upper bounded by $O(d\epsilon^{1/d})$. Check out Carbery Wright 2001.